# How permutation based FDR control methods take into account the correlation structure?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

There are a number of permutations-based False Discovery Rate (FDR) control methods, such as  SAM [1], dChip [2], Ge et al [3], Meinshausen [4], and Efron [5]. It's been said that in these methods, **the distribution of the test statistics under H0** is modeled empirically through permutations, which naturally considers the correlation among tests.

What does this mean? How permutation-based methods can take into account the correlated structure among tests into account?

[1] Tusher VG, Tibshirani R, Chu G: Significance analysis of microarrays applied to the ionizing radiation response. Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A 2001, 98(9):5116-5121.

[2] i C, Wong WH: DNA-Chip Analyzer (dChip). In The analysis of gene expression data: methods and software Edited by: Parmigiani G, Garrett ES, Irizarry R, Zeger SL. New York , Springer; 2003:120-141.

[3] Ge Y, Dudoit S, Speed TP: Resampling-based Multiple Testing for Micorarray Data Analysis. Test 2003, 12:1-77.

[4] Meinshausen N: False Discovery Control for Multiple Tests of Association Under General Dependence. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics 2006, 33:227-237

[5] Efron B: Correlation and Large-Scale Simultaneous Significance Testing. Journal of the American Statistical Association 2007, 102:93-103.